# Bootbox sending multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I have a Gridview and each row has a 'show modal' button. On clicking the button, the modal with a form on it opens, on which I am calling submit() action on 'onsubmit' as below:

```
function submit()
{
    bootbox.confirm({
        title: "Confirmation",
        message: "Are you sure?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-success '
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result)
            {
                $('#my_form').submit();
            }
            else
            {
                // return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Response on clicking bootbox confirm]

But this function sends ajax request, depending on the number of times the modal is closed and reopened. It sends multiple failed ajax requests and only the last one is successful. So in the image attached i have opened and closed the modal two times without submitting the form and while submitting the form third time, it sent three requests and so on.

P.S it sends single successful request in Firefox but sends multiple requests (based on how many times the modal is opened and closed) in Chrome

Comment: You  must have used event binding. You might want to unbind and then bind that event. To me it looks like multiple bindings on an event. Cant say without seeing some more code. Happens mostly when we use event bindings in a gridview or a datatable type of components.

Comment: Here I am logging 'test' on callback function and it gets printed only once but the call is sent multiple times (in Chrome only)
callback: function (result) {
            if (result)
            {
                console.log('test');
                $('#my_form').submit();
            }
}

Comment: I fixed it, instead of $('#my_form').submit(); I submitted the form via ajax like $.ajax({ url: myurl, data: $('#my_form').serialize(), success: function(result){//update DOM} })